# How can I config multi switch port efficiently?

Tags: cisco, switch, switchport

I have a Cisco 2960-24TT Switch, no I want to shutdown all the switch port, I have to enter the interface then execute `no shutdown` and exit it then re-do this steps.
how can I config multi switch port efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `interface range` to select multi continuous ports.

```
sw1(config)#interface range fastEthernet 0/2 -24
sw1(config-if-range)#shutdown
```